# Spring Boot, Angular2, Postgresql- Where is the best place to store images

Tags: angularjs, spring, image, postgresql

I am developing app using Spring Boot, Angular2 and Postgresql. I have list of items which I have to show on page. Each item have one thumbnail and another few photos (~ 4) which I put to gallery. My question is where is the best and the more efficient place to store image? My ideas:

- convert image to byte array and keep it in Postgresql
- keep all images inside application class-path (e.g resources/photos)
- Keep it on server class-path in external folder

Also solution must be easy for uploading new images from admin panel.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you store images in database, you have to serve them from database when requested. This way you create a lot of load on server and a lot of traffic between server and database. So, unless you need to sign files on the fly or add watermarks to images, you are deliberately creating a lot of performance overhead.

The common approach is storing meta information about your items (image file name, number of files, etc) in the database, but serving files statically from some folder. You can even configure them to be served with a different, more lightweight HTTP engine.